# How to search a nested dictionary and not care about top level key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, jekyll

So I am using lunr.js in my Jekyll application to implement a search feature and the results return correctly. The aim is to then display the list of results in the browser.

Here I get the results, then pass them to a func which handles the DOM manipulation.

```js
var results = idx.search(searchTerm); // Get lunr to perform a search
displaySearchResults(results, window.store);
```

The log of `console.log(window.store);` is the following:

```js
"python-2019-03-23-welcome-to-jekyll-html": Object { title: "test", category: "Python", url: "/python/2019/03/23/welcome-to-jekyll.html" }
```

The first key `python-2019-03-23-welcome-to-jekyll-html` doesn't matter as that will change depending on the number of posts. How can I get the values of `Object{}`?

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to JS, so if this is badly worded, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You grab the first key of the window.store and then you can get the values you want

```
const { title, category, url } = window.store[Object.keys(window.store)[0]];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to access only the values of the object. Example:

```
const myObj = {a: 1, b: 2}
Object.values(myObj)  // => [1, 2]
```